# Spring app Mybatis not logging exceptions

Tags: java, spring, logback, mybatis

I have a Spring app with Mybatis for DB access. I have the following logback config:

```
<configuration debug="true">



    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

    <logger name="my.packages" level="TRACE"/>

    <!-- SQL Logging -->
    <logger name="java.sql.*" level="DEBUG"/>

    <logger name="java.sql.Connection" level="TRACE"/>
    <logger name="java.sql.PreparedStatement" level="TRACE"/>
    <logger name="java.sql.ResultSet" level="TRACE"/>
    <logger name="java.sql.Statement" level="TRACE"/>

</configuration>
```

When I call a method from Mybatis, for example a select, and it has an error, I don't see the Exception in the console log.
When I check my Tomcat logs, I can see the error there:

```
Apr 23, 2015 9:15:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

### The error may exist in my/packages/persistence/Mapper.xml
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
... bla bla bla...
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
] with root cause
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
```

I don't get it why it's not logging where it should. 
If I surround the call to the mybatis call with a try/catch and log the error, it's working fine. But normally it should log also unchecked exceptions, or else I'll never see real issues.

Comment: Where do you want the logs to go? Are you configuring the `STDOUT` appender explicitly? Using `ConsoleAppender` in Tomcat will place the log messages in catalina.out.

Comment: @SeanKuhlman - I updated the configuration. I actually log to stdout, a rolling log file, and a socket appender. But they are identical...

Answer (score 0):

my configuration for mybatis 3.2.8 with spring boot has this setting in mybatis-config.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <settings>
    ...
    <setting name="logImpl" value="COMMONS_LOGGING"/>
    ...
  </settings>
</configuration>
```

You may find more detailed information in https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/logging.html

Answer (score 0):

In mybatis 3 there were a change from mybatis2; the log name is not `java.sql` anymore but is the dao executing the call.

suppose you have an Interface DAO for the class User

```
 package com.test.dao;

 public interface UserDao {
 ....//dao methods here
 }
```

Mybatis logs the error with the logger name com.test.dao so you must configure a logger with name com.test.dao

**EDIT**
if your dao are under the com.mypackages declared appender in logback then the problem is that you did miss the appender-ref element inside the logger element. 
Here is an example take from [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html).

Add an appender-ref to the logger and you shoud see the mybatis log

```
<logger name="chapters.configuration">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>
```

Comment: I already placed a logger with the package of my mybatis interfaces: <logger name="my.packages" level="TRACE"/>

Comment: I updated the response to show what is the problem (missing appender-ref)